# jquery adding up values on click

Tags: jquery, click, sum, addition

I hope you can help me.
At the moment I have this progressBar which is just using a predefined value on click, to show a percentage process in a div.

**Button:**

```
<a class="pbar" data-value="5" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

and here the js code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

progressBar(0, $('#progressBar'));

$('.pbar').click( function () {
    progressBar($(this).attr('data-value'), $('#progressBar'));

});


</script>
```

What I want now is, that every time the button ".pbar" is clicked, the data-value will be added by 5. 
So I click the button once, the bar shows 5%, I click again, it shows 10%, again 15% and so on.

Would appreciate your help.
Thank you.
Maze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$counter = 5;

$('.pbar').click( function () {
    $counter = $counter+5;
    progressBar($counter, $('#progressBar'));

});
```

Comment: thanks. only had to change the $counter=5 to 0, otherwise it would start with adding directly up to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope it helps you

```
$counter = $('.pbar').val();

$('.pbar').click( function () {
 $counter = $counter+5;
 progressBar($counter, $('#progressBar'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
progressBar(0, $('#progressBar'));

    $('.pbar').click( function () {
    var currentVal = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'));
    if (currentVal <= 100)
    {
        currentVal = currentVal + 5;
        progressBar(currentVal, $('#progressBar'));
        $(this).attr('data-value', currentVal);
    }
});
```